# How to create a pie chart in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I searched a lot of topics about creating pie chart in C#. Now I drag a chart from toolbox, I have intended to create a pie chart.

```
UssagePieChart.Series["CPU"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
UssagePieChart.Series["RAM"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
```

I have 2 numbers

```
int _xValue = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
int _yValue = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

Can I bind two numbers into each series of pie chart CPU(_xValue) and RAM(_yValue)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a sample like those found in the documentation of whatever chart control you are using? *Have* you checked the documentation?

Comment: Is this for winforms, wpf, asp or other?

Comment: I'm using winform sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should look something like this:-

```
  <asp:Chart ID="xxyyzz" runat="server" ImageType="Jpeg">
       <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="xx" YValueType="Int32" 
                 ChartType="Pie" ChartArea="Default" Legend="yyy" 
                 ToolTip="whatever your wanna do">
            </asp:Series>
       </Series>
       <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="Default">
                 <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
            </asp:ChartArea>
       </ChartAreas>
       <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="yyy">
            </asp:Legend>
       </Legends>
  </asp:Chart>
```

Lookup what Series, ChartAreas and Legends do.

While you can handle the two values on the C# side like:-

```
// key, value pair by creating a dictionary of your x and y.
xxyyzz.Series["xx"].Points.DataBindXY(dictionaryArray.Keys, dictionaryArray.Values); 
xxyyzz.Series["xx"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
```

Where basically you need to create a key,value Dictionary for your CPU and RAM values. Hope this gives you some direction. The rest is on you.

Comment: I will try to do this. Tks